# How to manage Php sessions in same page in php

Tags: javascript, php

I have a Index page in Php and a login link. When user login to the site then i want to redirect to the same page (index.php). At the place of login link I want to show the username of the user or client. I have a php login code like this

```html
 $error = '';
        
        if (isset($_POST['login']) && !empty($_POST['email']) 
           && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
   
            $email = $_POST['email'];
   $password = $_POST['password'];
   $sel_user = "select * from customer where email='$email' AND password='$password'";
   $run_user = mysql_query($sel_user);
   $check_user = mysql_num_rows($run_user);
   if($check_user == 1){
   $_SESSION['email']=$email;
   echo "<script>window.open('userinfo.php','_self')</script>";

           }
     else {
              $error = 'Invalid username or password';
           }
        }
```

in this code page is redirecting to another page after login but i want to redirect it to same page as index.php. And add links like my account and logout links instead of login link in index.php. I have a Php sessions page code like this

```html
 if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
    { 
        session_start(); 
    } 
$login_session=$_SESSION['email'];
if(!isset($_SESSION['email']))
{
    // not logged in
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit();
}
```

How can i make this for example like flipkart.com. Please help me.

Comment: Your queries are very dangerous. Your SQL is ready to get injected. Use PDO.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing:

Go for the code that you have already written for the login, i.e.,

```html
 $error = '';
        
        if (isset($_POST['login']) && !empty($_POST['email']) 
           && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
   
            $email = $_POST['email'];
   $password = $_POST['password'];
   $sel_user = "select * from customer where email='$email' AND password='$password'";
   $run_user = mysql_query($sel_user);
   $check_user = mysql_num_rows($run_user);
   if($check_user == 1){
   $_SESSION['email']=$email;
   echo "<script>window.open('userinfo.php','_self')</script>";

           }
     else {
              $error = 'Invalid username or password';
           }
        }
```

After this you do a check of the session variable

```html
 if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
    { 
        session_start(); 
    } 
$login_session=$_SESSION['email'];
if(!isset($_SESSION['email']))
{
    // not logged in
    header('Location: index.php');    //change the redirect page to index.php
    //now customize the menu accoringly
    echo "<nav class='your-class'>";
    echo "<li>";
    echo "<ul>Login</ul>";
    //Some more menus
    echo "</nav>";
    exit();
}
else
{
    header('Location: index.php'); //now configure the menu accordingly
    //now customize the menu accoringly on login
    echo "<nav class='your-class'>";
    echo "<li>";
    echo "<ul><a href="some link">My Account</a></ul>";
    //Some more menus
    echo "<ul><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></ul>";
    echo "</nav>";
}
```

But as far as I know this is somewhat tiresome and please try to avoid the queries like this. Use PDO instead. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
header('location:'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

instead of

```
echo "<script>window.open('userinfo.php','_self')</script>";
```

and for manage links

```
 <ul>
       <?php if(isset($_SESSION['email'])){ ?>
             <li><a href="logout.php" >Logout</a></li>
       <?php }else{ ?>
             <li><a href="index.php" >Home</a></li>
       <?php }?>
</ul>
```